# Deserializing JsonObject in REST client

Tags: java, json, serialization, jsonp, apache-tomee

I have problem while deserializing `javax.json.JsonObject` that is fetched from rest endpoint that returns `javax.json.JsonObject`. 

I'm using TomEE 7.0.2 web profile.

After little debugging, I found that exception coming from [Johnzone JsonObject implementation](https://github.com/apache/johnzon/blob/master/johnzon-core/src/main/java/org/apache/johnzon/core/JsonObjectImpl.java), and it is `NullPointerException` when using method `JsonObject.getJsonObject(name)`. 

From javadoc for [JsonObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html#getJsonObject-java.lang.String-) it saying that method should not throw exception if no mapping for `name` is found. Insted it should return `null`. 


That Json deserialization is meant to be little generic, and sometimes not all mappings are present. And this is problem for me because `JsonObject.getJsonObject(name)` is called in third party library.

Did I misunderstand something about why this `NullPointerException` is thrown? Is there workround to use another `javax.json.JsonObject` implementation when application war is run in TomEE server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test the existance with containsKey before reading the actual value.

Comment: Problem is that call to getJsonObject is nested in third party library, therfore I cannot call containsKey before getJsonObject to avoid that NullPointerException. Probably you are person that can actually answer questions from first post. Also, congrats on your work at tomee server and jsonb specification.

Comment: this was a bug in johnzon (will be rereleased in the coming days with the fix) cause spec (jsonp) requires this NPE when you get the direct value (getString() for instance) but not when you get a JsonStructure (getJsonObject() or getJsonString() for instance). In Johnzon we were always throwing a NPE. If you can't change this code the workaround would likely be to recreate the json object if it missed the data before passing it to the 3rd party. Not elegant but unblock you.

Comment: I did look in source code in Johnzon, and saw from where is comming that exception. Problem, that we have is that a lot of boilerplating code is in this library, connecting to rest endpoints, following of hateoas links, invocation of method, serialization and deserialization. And it was working until we put it on tomee. Just one more question, is fix for johnzon will be released on next tomee release?

Comment: yes, tomee follows johnzon releases. meantime - in dev - you can replace johnzon by the snapshot, tomee-maven-plugin or tomee-embedded-maven-plugin allow it easily

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're  catching the variable in a wrong type. Try var instead.

Comment: Can you add more information to your answer? What do you mean wrong type?